# How to sort string with numbers numerically in SQL?

Tags: sql

this is how it is currently sorted:

```
CRI-SU1
CRI-SU10
CRI-SU11
CRI-SU2
CRI-SU3
CRI-SU4
CRI-SU5
CRI-SU6
CRI-SU7
CRI-SU8
CRI-SU9
```

I wanted it to be sorted numerically like:

```
CRI-SU1
CRI-SU2
CRI-SU3
CRI-SU4
CRI-SU5
CRI-SU6
CRI-SU7
CRI-SU8
CRI-SU9
CRI-SU10
CRI-SU11
```

How do you sort it in SQL?
this is my sql statement...

```
SELECT systemUnitID FROM systemUnit ORDER BY systemUnitID
```

Comment: What's the specific database? The answer depends on the available database functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT systemUnitID 
FROM systemUnit
ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(systemUnitID, 'CRI-SU', '') As int)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the prefix always reads "CRI-SU", you can try to replace it with the empty string by using `replace()`. Then cast the result to an integer with `cast()` and order by the casted value. This should work in many DBMS.

```
SELECT systemunitid
       FROM systemunit
       ORDER BY cast(replace(systemunitid, 'CRI-SU', '') AS integer);
```